# Wrapping a function that returns a promise with another promise or not?

Tags: reactjs, redux, promise, react-redux, axios

I'm following some react and redux front-end tutorial and there is a part when we dispatch an action that issues an api request (using axios). The teacher wraps both the action function and the api call function with a new promise. I don't really understand why there's a need to do that since we can just return the promise that axios returns instead of wrapping it in a new promise. i'll post the code to be more clear:

**This is what was suggested in the tutorial:**

> *The api call function:*
>
> ```
> export function apiCall(method, path, data) {
>   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // <-- WRAPPING WITH A PROMISE
>       return axios[method](path, data)
>           .then(res=> {
>               return resolve(res.data);               
>           })
>           .catch(err => {
>               return reject(err.response.data.error);
>           });
>   });
> }
> ```
>
> *This is the redux action function (that calls apiCall):*
>
> ```
> export function authUser(type, userData) {
>   return dispatch => {            
>       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // <-- WRAPPING WITH A PROMISE
>           return apiCall("post", `/api/auth/${type}`, userData).then(             
>               ({ token, ...user }) => {                                       
>                   localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token); 
>                   dispatch(setCurrentUser(user));
>                   dispatch(removeError); 
>                   resolve();      
>               })
>               .catch(err => {
>                   dispatch(addError(err.message));        
>                   reject(); 
>               });             
>       });
>   };
> }
> ```
>
> *This is the function in the react component that's calling the redux action:*
>
> ```
> this.props.onAuth(authType, this.state).then(() => { // <-- onAuth is referring to authUser   
>   this.props.history.push("/");
> })
> .catch (() => { 
>   return;
> });
> ```

I don't understand why we need to wrap apiCall and authUser with promises, so i tried removing those promises and just returning the promise that axios returns from both authUser and apiCall:

**This is the modified version without the wrapping promises:**

*Is there any difference in the functionality from original implementation?*

> *The api call function:*
>
> ```
> export function apiCall(method, path, data) {
>   return axios[method](path, data)
>       .then(res => {
>           return (res.data);
>       })
>       .catch(err => {
>           throw (err.response.data.error);
>       });
> };
> ```
>
> *This is the redux action function (that calls apiCall):*
>
> ```
> export function authUser(type, userData) {
>   return dispatch => {
>       return apiCall("post", `/api/auth/${type}`, userData).then(     
>           ({ token, ...user }) => {
>               localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
>               dispatch(setCurrentUser(user)); 
>               dispatch(removeError); 
>           })
>           .catch(err => {
>               dispatch(addError(err.message));
>               throw err;
>           });
>   };
> }
> ```
>
> *The function in the react component can stay the same.*

Comment: Yes, there are slight differences (such as `reject()` vs `throw error`, which does reject with `undefined` vs the `err`), but you are totally right: the code in the tutorial is horrible and should be avoided. Your modified version is much better in all aspects.